# Cannot implicitly convert type to GraphicalApplication.Shapes to String

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I'm creating a unit test for one of the method of factory design pattern and when I create that class's object and try to call its method via that object then it says the above error.

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCircle()
        {
            //arrange
            String cmd = "circle 3";
            String exp_val = "new Circle";
            String actual_val = null;
            
            //act
            ShapeFactory factory_obj = new ShapeFactory();
            String[] cmd_values = cmd.ToLower().Split(' ');
            String code = cmd_values[0].Trim().ToLower();
            actual_val = factory_obj.getShape(code);

            //assert
            Assert.AreEqual(exp_val, actual_val);
        }
    }
```

Comment: getShape().ToStrinG()

Comment: `exp_val` is a `string`. `actual_val` is something else, presumably some sort of "shape" object. You can't compare them. Given that shape object, what about it would tell you that it is a circle? (It looks like you're trying to test that the factory returns a circle.) Does it have some property that says what sort of shape it is? Or is it determined by the object's type? Whatever that is, that's what you should assert.

Comment: @ScottHannen Yes it returns 'new Circle( )'  and I'm trying to store it in String hence it is passing error. What data type can  I use  to store it?

Comment: When you say that it returns "new Circle()` I suspect that it's returning an object - a new `Circle`, not a string. See if this works: `Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual_val, typeof(Circle));`

Comment: You can get rid of this line: `String actual_val = null;` and change the assignment to `var actual_val = factory_obj.getShape(code);` That way you're declaring it and assigning it on the same line. And using `var` instead of a type means that the variable is declared as whatever type `getShape` returns.